# How to remove list of previous data on razor ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I use jQuery ui datepicker to insert the date but I do not know how to remove the list of recommendations, which razor generates

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable autocomplete functionality of your web browser like this:

```
$('.datepicker').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");  
});
```

That way it will disable it on all datepicker fields. If you don't want to use jQuery then you can disable it manually by setting autocomplete like this:

```
<input type="text" name="someDate" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```